# Can't connect to puplic websites, but connects to VPN websites

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, website, intranet

We have a user's computer that is running Win7 Enterprise and is inside our company's domain. When ever he tries to connect to any public websites like Google, Facebook, Yahoo, or any other public website, he get's an error and can't access the website but it works fine with websites within the domain or VPN. We tried pinging the websites, it shows "General Failure" message. I have even tried Uninstalling and Reinstalling the network drivers, but that didn't help either. The other computers work fine with both Public and Privet websites.

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found i solution for the problem.

Getting the computer out of the domain and getting it back in seems to fix the problem.

Maybe it's not the optimal solution but it fixed it.